# How to connect one bot to multiply voice channels ? Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm creating a music bot discord but I figured out a miss. My bot can be only once on one voice channel. Is there way to connect this bot to more then one voice channel ?

Comment: Do you mean the bot being in multiple voice channels in the same server or different servers?

Comment: I mean both. I would like to let use bot on any voice channel

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have a discord bot be two different voice chats in the same server. Instead, you can make multiple bots that have the exact code (different bot tokens) and invite them all to the server, then allow them to join different voice chats. However, you can have one bot join multiple voice chats that are in **different servers** and have them play different music.

Comment: (Some servers that own their own music bot have 3 music channels and 3 of the same music bot.)

Comment: Then how can I make bot to join on other voice channels on different servers?

Comment: Just make your code cross server compatible

Answer (score 1):

That's true that you can't play discord bot on two voice channel on this same server. Instead you can play on different voice chanel if these channels are on different servers. Here is an example:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fs = require('fs');
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', async (message) => { 
    const broadcast = client.voice.createBroadcast();
    broadcast.play(ytdl('yt video link'));
    if (message.content === 'msg') {
        const connection  = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
        connection.play(broadcast);
    }
})


client.login('token')
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need to create **multiple instance** for the client to be able to handle multiple connection with multiple bot assigned to the `Client`.

For example we have 3 bots, we need to login these bots. How do we do that?
We can create a loop function to create instance for each bot.

We can use this method in class as property and store the instance in the map `Collection`, so that we can run the instance from there.

```js
class Bot {
    constructor() {
        this.commands = new Collection()
        this.aliases = new Collection()
        this.instance = {} // Provisioning param
        this.config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'json', 'bots.json')))
        this.init()
    }
    init() {
        const { bots } = this.config
        bots.forEach(async bot => {
            /**
             * Client creation based on bot list JSON
             * @Bot#config
             * We create multiple client dynamicaly that are refrenced to its own instance you can use this to manage every client before logged in
             * @Bot#InstanceName
             * */
            this[bot.name] = new Client({
              intents: [
                GatewayIntentBits.....
              ],
              partials: [
                Partials.......]
            })
            this[bot.name].player = new Player(this[bot.name]) // Here you can create your audio player class, so you can use it on different channel for every client that we created
            this[bot.name].instanceName = bot.name
            this[bot.name].instanceId = bot.id
            this[bot.name].login(process.env[bot.name])
        })
        this.run() // Run the Main function EG : Loop all client to listen every client event
    }
}
```

Then we iterate over `Array` to get property name, then we can listen to their `Event`.

```js
run () {
   const { bots } = this.config
   bots.forEach( (bot) => {
       this[bot.name].on(Event.Ready, (this[bot.name]) => {
          console.log('Client Ready')
       })
   })
}
```

Note that you must handle instance 1 as **default** client as the other are fallback ones. For example, if client 1 was playing, then client 2 will be ready and so on..

Now you can play the audio on different channel as long as you keep track the client instance by using if else condition to know which client are called by user and prevent duplicate response from the other client.